# Reading file.properties value in java code

Tags: java, spring, properties

I have a property file name documentum with the following contents

```
#test
dfs.repositoryName = CUDO
dfs.contextRoot = http://13.209.9.28:9080/services
dfs.username = 1234
dfs.password = fx8888
dfs.moduleName = core
```

I have configured this file in my beans.xml

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="false" />
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>file:${app.home}/documentum.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Now I want to do something like this but I am not getting how to achieve this in my java code.

```
String repository = ${dfs.repositoryName};
```

If I use @value annotation in the same class then it is working fine but if I use as a separate class like this

```
package au.com.fxa.sfdc.custdocs.util;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;

public class DocumentumConfigUtil {


    @Value("${dfs.repositoryName}")
    private String repositoryName;

    @Value("${dfs.contextRoot}")
    private String contextRoot;

    @Value("${dfs.username}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${dfs.password}")
    private String password;

    @Value("${dfs.module}")
    private String module;

    public String getRepositoryName() {
        return repositoryName;
    }

    public String getContextRoot() {
        return contextRoot;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public String getModule() {
        return module;
    }

}
```

and then create an object of this class and try to access through getter method it gives me null value.

Comment: As i can see you are talking about spring not webservices. If i am right Look for the @Value annotation.

Comment: yes sorry creating web service using apache cxf and spring framework.

Comment: `@Value` like `@Autowired` will only work on spring managed beans. If you create an instance yourself, spring will know nothing about that bean and thus ignore the `@Value`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `@Value` annotation.

Define a class property like

```
@Value("${dfs.repositoryName}")
String repository
```

Comment: Thanks Jens. It is working if I define in the same class. But if I define the properties in another class and via getter try to access these properties, it gives me null.

Comment: @Adeel Edit your question, add a Headline UPDATE and share it there, or do you have a github repo?

Comment: @Adeel This class is not a spring bean, so the injection of properties does not work. Add the `@Configuration` Annotation to the class

Comment: I added the @configuration and got exception saying org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field :(

Comment: @Adeel Which field?

Comment: Sorry my bad.  Actually it is again giving me null value even after adding @configuration. I am accessing like this   DocumentumConfigUtil documentumConfigUtil = new DocumentumConfigUtil();
  System.out.println(documentumConfigUtil.getRepositoryName());

Comment: @Adeel I the class in a package wich will be scanned by spring for annotations?

Comment: in my beans.xml 
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="au.com.fxa.sfdc.custdocs" /> is this what you are asking ?

Comment: How you Import the class where you call the getter?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149690/discussion-between-jens-and-adeel).